# how to get the result without conditional expressions

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, conditional, algebraic-manipulation

I am working with JAVA API and send a relation to kernel, then receive the returned solved result. Although I explicitly mentioned in my relation to have Integer Elements, the returned expressions says the conditions. means it says if x is INT etc. I do not need it. Is there any way not to get that? a sample provided .

```
 Simplify[Solve[
  Exists[{xPP, yPP, zPP, wPP}, Element[ {x, y, z, w}, Integers], 
   wPP == w && xPP == 2 + x && yPP == 2 + x + y && zPP == z &&
    (
     (xPP < yPP && wP == wPP && xP == xPP && yP == yPP && 
        zP == xPP + yPP)
      ||
      (! xPP < yPP && zPP > 10 && wP == wPP && xP == xPP && 
        yP == yPP && zP == 2 + yPP
       )
     )
   ]]]
```

Part of the returned relation: as you see there is "if" part which makes my code wrong. I just need  **wp->p && y>=1**

```
{{wP->w if (w|x|y|z)\[Element]\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]&&y>=1
```

Comment: Add `Element[{x, y, z, w}, Integers]` to the `Simplify` as well. This won't get rid of the condition altogether though, since the condition that e.g. y>=1 will remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Add `Element[{x, y, z, w}, Integers]`as an assumption to the [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) and replace [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) with [`And`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html)

```
Off[Solve::svars]

Simplify[
  Solve[
   Exists[{xPP, yPP, zPP, wPP},
    Element[{x, y, z, w}, Integers], 
    wPP == w && xPP == 2 + x && yPP == 2 + x + y && 
     zPP == 
      z && ((xPP < yPP && wP == wPP && xP == xPP && yP == yPP && 
         zP == xPP + yPP) ||
       (! xPP < yPP && zPP > 10 && wP == wPP && 
         xP == xPP && yP == yPP && zP == 2 + yPP))]],
  Element[{x, y, z, w}, Integers]] /.
 ConditionalExpression :> And

(* {{wP -> w && y >= 1, xP -> 2 + x && y >= 1, yP -> 2 + x + y && y >= 1, 
  zP -> 4 + 2 x + y && y >= 1}, {wP -> w && y <= 0 && z >= 11, 
  xP -> 2 + x && y <= 0 && z >= 11, yP -> 2 + x + y && y <= 0 && z >= 11, 
  zP -> 4 + x + y && y <= 0 && z >= 11}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pattern matching, the unwanted part of the output can be filtered.

```
Simplify[Solve[
   Exists[{xPP, yPP, zPP, wPP}, Element[{x, y, z, w}, Integers], 
    wPP == w && xPP == 2 + x && yPP == 2 + x + y && 
     zPP == z && ((xPP < yPP && wP == wPP && xP == xPP && yP == yPP &&
          zP == xPP + yPP) || (! xPP < yPP && zPP > 10 && wP == wPP &&
          xP == xPP && yP == yPP && zP == 2 + yPP))]]] /. 
 Rule[v1_, 
   ConditionalExpression[v2_, And[Element[x__, Integers], v3_]]] -> 
  Rule[v1, And[v2, v3]]
```

[image]